# JavaScript wait for promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, resolve

I need `fetchAndInstantiate` to wait before someVariable is defined (by an external process). Function `getResult` detects when said variable is defined.

I have this two functions:

```
async function getResult(){
    if(typeof someVariable !== 'undefined'){
        console.log('yup');
        Promise.resolved(someVariable);
    }else{
        console.log('nop');
        setTimeout(getResult, 250);
    }
}

fetchAndInstantiate = async function(a, b, c){
    delete someVariable;
    console.log('called fetchAndInstantiate');
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('wasmcall', {detail: { wasm_mod: a, function: b, args: c}}));
    await getResult().then(function(result){return result;});
}
```

function `fetchAndInstantiate` calls function `getResult` and I want it to wait until the promise resolves. BUT `getResult` is returning an undefined promisse when `setTimeout` is called.

How can I make `getResult` only resolve when someVariable is defined?

Comment: _"BUT `getResult` is returning an undefined promissewhen `setTimeout` is called"_ - It will always "return" `undefined` because you're not returning anything (useful) in `getResult`

Comment: @Andreas any ideas on how I can call ```setTimeout``` without ```getResult``` returning undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that `getResult` returns a promise as you expect.

Also, using `setInterval` will accomplish what you want without that messy code.

```
async function getResult(){
    var result = await new Promise(function(resolve) {
    const interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(typeof someVariable !== 'undefined'){
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve(someVariable);
      }
    }, 250);
  });
  return result;
}

fetchAndInstantiate = async function(a, b, c){
    delete someVariable;
    console.log('called fetchAndInstantiate');
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('wasmcall', {detail: { wasm_mod: a, function: b, args: c}}));
    var result = await getResult();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an asynchronous delay:

```
const delay = milliseconds => new Promise(resolve, setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
```

And use this in your async function:

```
async function getResultAsync() {
    while (true) {
        if (typeof someVariable !== 'undefined') {
            return someVariable;
        }
        await delay(250);
    }
}
```

This will continue to wait until `someVariable` is defined, with a 250 millisecond delay between each check, without blocking.

Note that you must return something inside your async function; this resolves the `Promise` that is returned.

Then consume in your `fetchAndInstantiate` function:

```
fetchAndInstantiate = async function(a, b, c) {
    delete someVariable;
    console.log('called fetchAndInstantiate');
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('wasmcall', {detail: { wasm_mod: a, function: b, args: c}}));
    await getResultAsync();
}
```

You don't need to mix `await` with `then()`; `await` unwaps the `Promise` resolution for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I must have missed this notification sorry. I haven't actually tried your way but it looks like it would have solved it ! thanks again